# Mapping from the integers to rationals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My book gives the following definition of mapping:

> Definition: If $S$ and $T$ are nonempty sets then a mapping from $S$
>   to $T$ is a subset, $M$, of $S \times T$ such that for every $s \in S$
>   there's a unique $t \in T$ such that the ordered pair $(s, t) \in M.$

I'm then given the following example:

> Example: Let $J$ be the set of integers and $S = \left\{(m, n)\in J
>  \times J | n \ne 0\right\}$; let $T$ be the set of rational numbers;
>   define $\tau: S \to T$ by $(m, n)\tau = \frac{m}{n}$ for every
>   $(m, n) \in S$.

Could someone please explain why this is a mapping and how it fits the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really do set theory, but let's give these definitions a go. :)

What I believe it means by a subset $M$ of $S \times T$ is that the mapping maps $s \mapsto t$. Note that this must be an *ordered* pair, since $\tau : s \mapsto t$ is a very different claim from $\tau : t \mapsto s$, for $s \in S$ and $t \in T$.

Fix $s \in S$. So we need to show that there exists a unique $t \in T$ such that the (ordered) pair $(s,t) \in M$, ie there exists a unique $t \in T$ such that $\tau(s) = t$. In this case, let's write $s = (m,n)$ with $n \neq 0$. Note that $\tau(s) = \tau((m,n)) = m/n$ and, since $n \neq 0$, $m/n \in T$. In summary, given $s \in S$, we choose $t = m/n$, where $(m,n)$ is such that $s = (m,n)$.

(At some points, this might seem like labouring the point rather, but I hope that it helps.)

---

Just to add, to labour the point further, I guess what was confusing you (and me initially) was that at one point it talks about a mapping as a subset of $S \times T$ and then later as a 'function'. By "a mapping $\tau : s \mapsto t$", it means the subset $M = \{ (s,t) \in S \times T \mid s \in S, t = \tau(s) \}$. (At the very least, this is my understanding of the given definitions.)

Answer (score 1):

Given the definitions of $J, S, T$ and $\tau$,

$$
\tau = \left\{\left((m,n),\frac m n\right) \mid m,n\in J, n\ne 0 \right\} \subseteq S\times T.
$$